# Prevent keyboard from open after calling to SearchItem.expandActionView()

Tags: android, search, keyboard

Im trying to prevent keyboard from open when showing search view using mSearchItem.expandActionView()

Clearing focus from the search view doesn't work:

```
mSearchItem.getActionView().clearFocus();
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
mSearchItem.getActionView().clearFocus();
```

to

```
mSearchItem.clearFocus();
```

Should help u out.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
public static void hideSoftKeyboard(Activity activity) {
    View focusedView = activity.getWindow().getCurrentFocus();
    if (focusedView != null && focusedView.isFocused()) {
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(focusedView.getWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
    }
}
```